# Font Awesome free brand won't load on ios safari

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I'm using Vue.js with this package https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#why-use-the-concept-of-a-library

Font Awesome won't load some of the icons from **@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons**

It loads normally on Chrome macOS

[image]

But some won't load on Safari ios

[image]

This is how I import and use it

```
import {
    faFacebookF,
    faLine,
    faYoutube,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

library.add([
    faFacebookF,
    faLine,
    faYoutube,
]);
```

```
 <font-awesome-icon :icon="{ prefix: 'fab', iconName: facebook-f }"/>
 <font-awesome-icon :icon="{ prefix: 'fab', iconName: youtube }"/>
 <font-awesome-icon :icon="{ prefix: 'fab', iconName: line }"/>
```

Comment: fortawesome? Not font?

Comment: It actually is vue-fontawesome package which is  "Font Awesome 5 Vue component using SVG with JS" as the package description

Comment: @FeiWhang were you able to resolve it?